# Vaadin 8 ComboBox set items as html not work

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

the code:

```
    ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>("TEST-Combo");
    comboBox.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
    comboBox.setItemCaptionGenerator(item -> "<b>" + item + "</b>");
    comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    comboBox.setItems("xxx", "<i>yyy</i>", "<b>zzz</b>");
```

reuslt:

[image]

Is it Vaadin Bug or my failure?

**EDIT**

Vaadin Version 8.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method
`comboBox.setCaptionAsHtml(true)` does not affect items. It sets the mode of the ComboBox caption, which in your case is *"TEST-Combo"*.

There is currently no HTML support for items in ComboBox in Vaadin 8.

However there is `comboBox.setStyleGenerator()` which allows you to set item specific styles in CSS. I.e. if you case is to set bold font, you can set something like

> comboBox.setStyleGenerator(item -> item.isImportant() ? "bold-font" : "");

and in theme SCSS mixin

```
.bold-font {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a missing feature. To help prevent XSS vulnerabilities, the item captions are rendered as plain text instead of HTML. There is a [ticket](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/2132) about making it possible to configure it to show the contents as HTML, but it has been inactive for a long time so it's not very likely that it would be fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom renderer (an `HtmlRenderer` in your case):

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setRenderer( new HtmlRenderer() );
```

This makes your combo items being rendered in HTML

A more sophisticated renderer is explained here:
https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-components

Comment: Yes, the renderer mechanism in ComboBox is new feature added in Vaadin 10+ versions.